# Discord.py bot wont display text with prefix

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

bot = Bot(command_prefix='!')
TOKEN = 'TOKEN GOES HERE'

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Bot connected as {bot.user}')
    await bot.change_presence(activity = discord.Game('SAO'))

#Bellow this it the trouble part
@bot.command(name='test')
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == 'test':
        await message.channel.send('Testing 1 2 3!')

    await bot.process_commands(message)


    
bot.run(TOKEN)
```

I need help getting it to display 'Test 1 2 3!' when I type '!test'? Why  the heck is it so hard to post ughhhhh they need more detail but I dint know what else to tell you.

Comment: Make sure you don't give out your token. Hopefully, discord scanned the post and reset your token.

Answer (score 0):

The message comes fully as you typed it. You are checking if the user has typed in "test". Maybe change your if statement to be:

```py
if message.content == "!test":
```

Comment: Is there any other way to do it

Comment: Not really, there's tactics you can employ to make it easier. Such as using the startswith method to check if its a command string. Example: `message.content.startswith("!")`.

Comment: can you send in code demonstrating how to do that?

Comment: You can check by printing it out right after the `on_message` declaration: `print(message.content.startswith("!"))`.

You can also test it out from a string literal: `print("!this-is-true".startswith("!")` and `print("this-is-false!".startswith("!")`

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing the `commands` with the `events`, `on_message` is an event not a command. according to your example you should use commands. Here is an example

Command

```py
#Run this using !test
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Testing 1 2 3!')
```

Event

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == 'hey':
        await message.channel.send('Hello')
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

[Read more on commands](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#commands)